# Examples on manim are not working and it does not show any error

Tags: manim

I have followed many tutorials on how to install it, most recently I followed @theorem by Beethoven tutorial on youtube, but when I execute the line **python3 manim.py example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -f** it shows well... nothing, at all, zero, nada. Not even an error.

I have tried to search for a File where the video might be stored by I can't find it, I even changed the MEDIA_DIR.txt file to a known location and it doesn't work.

Comment: `-f` is discontinued, you have to use `-pl` or similar, you can watch my Rendering Settings video for more information.